# How can I Convert Normal timestamp to Epoch Timestamp in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

Question 1:
Convert the human readable date to epoch timestamp/time as on the start of the day?
Example.
If the INPUT date is 21-01-2020, print the epoch time at the start of the day i.e 12:00 AM
Conditions:
Date limit: 01-01-1970 to 
Input Description:
The input date will be in any of the following format.

1. dd/mm/yyyy
2. mm/dd/yyyy
3. dd-mm-yyyy
4. mm-dd-yyyy
5. dd.mm.yyyy
6. mm.dd.yyyy
7. ddmmyyyy
8. mmddyyyy

Output Description:
For all the types of above input date, the output should be an Epoch timestamp/time.

Question 1 – Date to Epoch timestamp

Exceptions:
Any input date other than the given formats must be handled and a message "Unable to convert the
provided date" must be printed.

More Examples:

Example 1
Input: 19-01-2020
Output: 1579392000

Example 2
Input: 31122012
Output: 1356912000

Example 3
Input: 251220202
Output: Unable to convert the provided date

Example 4
Input: 17:04:2020
Output: Unable to convert the provided date

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: The question (I mean the homework assignment) should give information on the time zone of the input - otherwise, the result is ambiguous since Python treats naive datetime as local time.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

my_input = input("Enter date: ")
my_input = re.sub("/", "-", my_input)
my_input = re.sub(".", "-", my_input)

try:
    out = datetime.strptime(my_input, "%d-%m-%Y").timestamp()
except Exception:
    try:
        out = datetime.strptime(my_input, "%d%m%Y").timestamp()
    except Exception:
        out = "Unable to convert the provided date"

print(out)
```

Comment: since no time zone information is given for the input, the result of this code will depend on the time zone setting of the machine you run this on.

Comment: Depends on input timezone. Want to change timezone?